# autofill won't fill until last row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a code for inserting formula at some row in a module

Then I add a new module to autofill the formula depending on C column (if C 15 data then it autofill down 15)

The autofill works manually to what I expected, but when I set to Private Sub for Workbook_Open, the autofill doesn't fill the last row (if 15 data, the macro only fill until row 14)

Below is my autofill code

```
Sub AutoFill()

lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A6:B6").AutoFill Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A6:B" & lr), Type:=xlFillDefault
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D6:S6").AutoFill Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D6:S" & lr), Type:=xlFillDefault


End Sub
```

How do I make this code run until the last row when I set it to Private Sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Range.AutoFill

- The important difference is that in this solution the `.Cells` are qualified `ws.Cells` i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)` to ensure that the correct worksheet is being searched. You can use variables to shorten the lines.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFill()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim lrCell As Range
    Set lrCell = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If lrCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty worksheet
    
    Dim lr As Long: lr = lrCell.Row
    If lr < 7 Then Exit Sub ' no data below
    
    ws.Range("A6:B6").AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("A6:B" & lr), Type:=xlFillDefault
    ws.Range("D6:S6").AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("D6:S" & lr), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Comment: OMG! It works! Thank you Sir!
So, is it that first I need to declare the range first?

Comment: In your code you did `lr = Cells.Find(...` but you should have done `lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(...`. The same with `Cells(1, 1)`, you should have done `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cell(1, 1)`. Also, when you do `lr = Cells.Find(...).Row`, you are assuming that a cell will be found but if no cell is found, an error will occur. It is, therefore, best to (attempt to) find the cell and test if it **was not found** with e.g. `If lrCell Is Nothing Then` or with `If Not lrCell Is Nothing Then` if it **was found**. Only if it was found, you can continue with `lr = lrCell.Row`.

Comment: I see, Thank you for the explanation. Will keep in mind that I need to give ThisWorkbook.Sheets code 
again, very appreciate it